# Docker build ADD vs RUN curl

Tags: curl, docker, dockerfile

If I run a dockerfile where I have a command like

```
RUN curl -o file.txt http://X.X.X.X/path/to/file/file.txt
```

the build works, whereas if I use

```
ADD http://X.X.X.X/path/to/file/file.txt file.txt
```

The build fails and it complains about

```
Got HTTP status code >= 400: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Is there something about ADD that I'm not understanding?

**Edit** the file is also accessible through the docker host.

Answer (score 18):

[`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) is executed in docker host.

> The `ADD` instruction copies new files, directories or remote file URLs
>   from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the image at the path
>   `<dest>`.

[`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) is executed inside your container.

> The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of
>   the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed
>   image will be used for the next step in the `Dockerfile`.

Specifically the command `RUN curl -o file.txt http://X.X.X.X/path/to/file/file.txt` executes curl that must have already been installed in the image we are using. If the curl command has not been installed (and is not present in the base image) the entire `RUN` command fails.
Instead the command `ADD` url can be performed even without having installed `curl` (or analogues) inside the container just because it is executed by the host (it uses the Go libraries with which it is written docker) during the creation of our image.

---

Is `http://X.X.X.X/path/to/file/file.txt` accessible outside of your docker container?

**Edit**: as confirmed by the author of the question:

> My docker host lives behind a firewall that has a proxy set in the
>   `/etc/default/docker` file. So while I wanted to grab a file internal
>   to the network I'm on, the proxy caused it to look outside the
>   network.

Comment: Oh didn't know that, good to know. And yes, it is definitely accessible through curl on the docker host.

Comment: Thank you fox91 for the hint as to the cause. My docker host lives behind a firewall that has a proxy set in the /etc/default/docker file. So while I wanted to grab a file internal to the network I'm on, the proxy caused it to look outside the network. The fact that ADD is executed using the docker host environment was important in diagnosing this issue.