# Is there any cache advantage to using ADD <url> vs RUN wget/curl <url> in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any advantage to layer cache invalidation by using `ADD` instead of `RUN`?

**Background**

I frequently see Dockerfiles that install wget or curl just to `RUN wget …` or `RUN curl …` to install some dependency that cannot be found in package management.

I suspect these could be converted to simple `ADD <url> <dest>` lines, and that would at least obviate the need for adding curl or wget to the image.

Further, it seems like the docker daemon could rely on HTTP cache invalidation to inform its own layer cache invalidation. At a minimum (e.g. in the absence of HTTP cache headers), it could `GET` the resource, hash it, and calculate invalidation the same way it does for local files.

**NOTE:** I am familiar with the *usage* of `Add` vs `RUN …`, but I am looking for a strong reason to choose one over the other. In particular, I want to know if `ADD <url>` can behave any more intelligently with regard to layer cache invalidation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker build ADD vs RUN curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171851/docker-build-add-vs-run-curl)

Comment: No, but thank you @Ouroborus. I'm familiar with the differences in _using_ the two, but I'm looking for stronger rationale for why to choose one or the other. Specifically, I'm looking for their ramifications on layer cache invalidation.

Comment: I can tell you why I use `RUN apt-get install wget`. Because I am a docker noob that does not know the ADD command. I found many examples using that way, so I thought that is the way to do it. I remove the package and clean up apt after I use it however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to use `RUN wget …` or `RUN curl …` to download an archive instead of `ADD`. This allows you to extract the archive files and delete the downloaded file in the same `RUN` command. This prevents the downloaded file from being stored in the image.

As the Docker documentation says: "[using ADD to fetch packages from remote URLs is strongly discouraged](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache:%7E:text=using%20ADD%20to%20fetch%20packages%20from%20remote%20URLs%20is%20strongly%20discouraged)"

Avoid using `ADD` to download an archive and then extracting it in separate `RUN` commands, as this will create an intermediate file that will be stored in the image. Due to how Docker works, subsequent
`RUN` command can only mark the file as deleted, but not actually remove it. For example, the following Dockerfile will create an intermediate file called `big.tar.xz` in the image:

```
ADD https://example.com/big.tar.xz /usr/src/things/
RUN tar -xJf /usr/src/things/big.tar.xz -C /usr/src/things
RUN make -C /usr/src/things all
```

Instead, you can use a single `RUN` command to download the archive, extract it, and run the make command, as shown in the following Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/things \
    && curl -SL https://example.com/big.tar.xz \
    | tar -xJC /usr/src/things \
    && make -C /usr/src/things all
```

This Dockerfile will not create any intermediate files, and the downloaded file will not be stored in the image.

Comment: Thanks. It might help to clarify that even with a subsequent `RUN rm …` the intermediate file persists in a layer in the resulting image. That is ultimately why I went with `RUN` and why I moved my acceptance to this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Certainly.

The `RUN` instruction will not invalidate the cache unless its text changes. So if the remote file is updated, you won't get it. Docker will use the cached layer.

The `ADD` instruction will always download the file and the cache will be invalidated if the checksum of the file no longer matches.

I would recommend using `ADD` instead of `RUN wget ...` or `RUN curl ...`. I imagine people use the latter as its more familiar, but the `ADD` instruction is quite powerful. It can untar files and set ownership. It's also considered best practice to avoid downloading any packages that are not necessary for your process to run (though there are multiple ways to accomplish this, like using multi-stage builds).

Docs on cache invalidation:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache